# Extra Applications folder being created inside /Applications (macOS Sierra)

Tags: macos, permissions, finder

A few months ago, I noticed that there was duplicate 'Applications' folder inside of /Applications. There was nothing in it, so I deleted the folder. Ever since then the folder keeps reappearing at [seemingly] random times. I checked the folders permissions and owners, and it appears that its owned by 'root', in 'wheel' group. Other than that, I know nothing about it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished chatting with Apple about this and I was told that this is OK. That empty Application folder will be created at boot time if you delete it. I can forward the email from my chat session on request. I am surprised because it was never like that in passed macOSes. I suspect a bug that is being palmed off as a feature :)